# Prolog Program to Find Square of Natural Numbers

Tags: iterator, prolog, perfect-square

My code below is meant to generate the square of natural numbers in order

(i.e `sq(X). -> X=0; X=1; X=4; X=9; X=16; ...`)

```
nat(0).
nat(X) :- nat(Y), Z is Y+1, X is Z*Z.
```

but the answer I am getting is:

1

```
0 ?- nat(X).

X = 0 ;

X = 1 ;

X = 4 ;

X = 25 ;

X = 676
```

Should be a quick fix, but I've spent longer on this than I'd like to say. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your nat/1 really seems to return a different sequence. Should be

```
nat(0).
nat(X) :- nat(Y), X is Y+1.
```

and then, a *different* predicate for square

```
sq(X) :- % call nat/1, square it...
```

please complete the code

Comment: Yep, stupid fix indeed, I've been looking at code for so long that I was intent on putting it all into one predicate as opposed to splitting it up. Thanks CapelliC, great answer!

    `nat(0).`


    `nat(X) :- nat(Y), X is Y+1.`


    `sq(X) :- nat(Y), X is Y*Y.`